# How to access the base namespace in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, namespaces

I'm writing code in a namespace where the File module exists (inside another module)

And I need to access the ruby File class.

In php this could be done like this: \File

How to do that in ruby?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
::File
```

Prefixing with `::` accesses the 'root' of the namespace tree.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure what you're asking, but if you are inside of module `Foo` and you reference class `Bar`, then ruby will look for `Foo::Bar`. To look just for `Bar`, you should reference `::Bar` (of course, this `Bar` should be defined in "global" scope, outside of `Foo`).