# Namespace collision with top-level methods

Tags: ruby

I have the following Ruby namespace problem:

I have a number of top-level methods in a "library", among these I have a get_name(param) method.
The problem is that I want to use this get_name(param) method inside a class that has its own get_name() method (without param!).
Of course this results in a problem as the 2 methods are different and the new one in the class overrides the top-level one.

Is there a way to do something like this:

```
def get_name(param)
  puts param
end

class Foo 
  def get_name()
    puts "name"
  end
  def bar()
    self.get_name() #should work and print name, i.e. it uses the get_name method of Foo
    get_name("abc") #should work and print abc, i.e. it uses the top-level method
  end
end
```

I would like to know if there is an easy way to achieve this without having to alter the name or scope of the top-level methods. (The goal is to have those available without modification as global methods, but still be able to call instance methods of Foo without errors.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10064334/how-to-access-the-base-namespace-in-ruby might help

Comment: My recommendation: just create an alias in the top level. Aliases don't modify their preimages ;-)

Comment: That does not make sense. The top level `get_name` method is an instance method, but you are trying to call it on a `Foo` instance.

Answer (score 2):

If the library methods are really top-level methods and are not part of any class or module, then, they will get defined as `private` methods of `Object` class.

You can do following to invoke it:

```
  def bar()
    self.get_name()
    Object.send(:get_name, "abc")  # Will print "abc" to console
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

The so called "top level method" is only a method of `main` object, which is only an `Object`. If you want that method to be able to be called (almost) anywhere, you should make it a **kernel method**.

```
module Kernel
  def get_name(param)
    puts param
  end
end
```

Note that `Kernel` is almost at the tail of any classes ancestors chain (before `BasicObject`), which means almost all the objects are a `Kernel`. So in your `Foo` class, you can override it like this:

```
class Foo
  def get_name(*args)
    return super if args.any?
    puts 'name'
  end
end
```

### Edit

If you can't make those top level methods kernel methods, you can store the `main` object in a constant or a global variable, and call those top level methods on it.

```
$main = self

class Foo
  def get_name(*args)
    return $main.send(:get_name, *args) if args.any?
    puts 'name' 
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

First off: there is no such thing as a "top-level method". There is exactly one kind of method in Ruby: instance methods.

The method you are referring to is a `private` instance method of `Object`. Since `Object` is a superclass of almost any other class (excluding `Object` and its superclasses), if you are sure that there are no other methods with the same name somewhere else in the inheritance hierarchy, you could use `Method#super_method` to get access to the method and then call it:

```
def get_name(param)
  puts param
end

class Foo 
  def get_name
    puts 'name'
  end

  def bar
    get_name #should work and print name, i.e. it uses the get_name method of Foo
    method(:get_name).super_method.('abc') #should work and print abc, i.e. it uses the top-level method
  end
end

Foo.new.bar
# name
# abc
```

Alternatively, if you *don't* know whether there are any *other* methods by the same name within the inheritance hierarchy, you could grab a reference to the `UnboundMethod` directly from `Object` and then `bind` and `call` it:

```
class Foo 
  def bar
    get_name #should work and print name, i.e. it uses the get_name method of Foo
    Object.instance_method(:get_name).bind(self).('abc') #should work and print abc, i.e. it uses the top-level method
  end
end

Foo.new.bar
# name
# abc
```